# github.com indents our code strangely

Tags: netbeans, github, styles, indentation

[This is where github.com is doing bad indentation](https://github.com/coderodde/finalib/blob/master/src/main/java/fi/helsinki/finalib/SimplificationAlgorithm.java)

How can we fix this? (Code was written on NetBeans 7.2.)

Comment: And the indentation looks fine to me!

Comment: You're mixing tabs and spaces. A recipy for disaster.

Comment: @Paddyd The indentation is wrong. It seems that github's tabs are 8 spaces wide (contrary to the usual 4).

Comment: @aross: Since when is Tab "usually" 4? *Indentation width* varies (common values are 2, 4 and 8); but *Tab width*, unless defined otherwise, is 8, as a matter of an unwritten standard. Open any general-purpose editor without messing with configuration, use any *NIX command, it will stop at every 8th character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix tabs and spaces. Most editors use a tab width of 4 spaces, but this is not standard in any way. Make up your mind on whether to use tabs or spaces for indenting.

Personally I prefer spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to Preferences -> Editor -> Formatting, setting tab size to 4 spaces, then clicking Source -> Format and, finally, recommitting to github.com.